# Accessing asp.net web server controls from jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

In my C# asp.net 3.5 web application I am having controls like div tag inside that one textbox and one check box and the page is having a submit button. So in this submit button click I want to make the controls inside the div tag visible.. I am calling a JQuery function to do this. All the statements are getting executed but the control is not visible..
Following is the code in my JQuery function

```
$("input[name$='QuestionAndAnswerEditorDiv']").show();
$("input[name$='answerLabel1']").show()
$("input[name$='wmd-AnswerTextBox']").show()
```

My div tag and its controls in the user control page are like the following

```
 <div id="QuestionAndAnswerEditorDiv" runat="server">
 <div id="wmd-button-bar" class="wmd-panel wmd-button-row"></div> 
 <textarea name="QuestionandAnswerTextArea" runat="server" id="AnswerTextBox" onkeyup="prettyPrint();" class="wmd-input editor" cols="92" rows="15"/><div class="wmd-preview text-preview preview" style="-ms-word-wrap: break-word;"></div>
```

As I noticed these controls are make visible=false in another page so they are not coming in the page source.. So Let me know how to work these controls now

Comment: How are you hiding these elements in the first place?  They can't be 'shown' without first being 'hidden' in the client-side.  If you are hiding in code-behind, they will not even show in the DOM

Comment: Could you please include your HTML markup as well?

Comment: so as i suggested in my answer make use of proper selctor so that this will work for you

Comment: As I noticed these controls are make visible=false in another page so they are not coming in the page source.. So Let me know how to work these controls now

Answer (score 1):

all web server controls in asp.net < 4 are not rendered using their given name.
to use the rendered name use Control.ClientID

Answer (score 1):

Setting QuestionAndAnswerEditorDiv.Visible = false; will mean that it doesn't get rendered to the page. In your code behind do the following:

```
QuestionAndAnswerEditorDiv.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");
QuestionandAnswerTextArea.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");
```

the JQuery show() function uses the display property and will set it to "block", which will make it visible.

Comment: I tried this also but its also not working for me. I updated my question please take a look into it

Comment: @stackuser1 - If you continue to hide them on the server in the code-behind they will never show in the HTML source to make them visible on the client.  Follow @Daniel Dyson's example above and replace your visible=false with his snippet.

Answer (score 0):

This may not work because div is not going to render as input element and label is rendered as span element in asp.net  so check for the type of controls

```
for div
$("div[name$='QuestionAndAnswerEditorDiv']").show();

for label
$("span[name$='answerLabel1']").show()

for textbox
$("input[name$='wmd-AnswerTextBox']").show()
```

**Edit :**

so as i suggested in my answer make use of proper jquery selctor so that this will work for you

**Edit 1**

So rather than making control `visible= false` set there sytles to `disply:none` so that controls avaialbe on you page and you can play with them using jquery/javascript